# changing font (bold/italic) on hover for display:table-cell shrinks width

Tags: css

Just as the title reads. When hovering over a li displaying as table-cell that changes font-weight, the width shrinks/grows.

I'm using display:table on the `ul` because I need the `li`s to evenly span the container

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/elzi/trXn4/5/ UPDATED.

Maybe there's no really dynamic way to do it and I need to set some widths for some of the `li`s with more text?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tables shrink/expand to give the most content the most room, unless you tell them otherwise.

You can add `width: 25%;` to your `li` ([**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/trXn4/3/)), or you can add `table-layout: fixed;` to the `ul` ([**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/trXn4/4/)).

Comment: I gave a bad example in my fiddle because not all the text will be the same width... example: http://jsfiddle.net/elzi/trXn4/5/

Comment: @elzi And this is the fundamental problem with `table`s in HTML. You might even have to just use jQuery to, on load, get the width of each table cell using `.outerWidth()`, then apply it as an inline style.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it does:)
If your list items are static you can set a fixed width by adding

```
width: xxxpx;
```

to the li definition

Comment: But some lis are bigger than others... jsFiddle was a bad example

Comment: Well, if they are still static, you can set the width for each li...By changing the font weight, you're changing the size of the li's content.  So unless you fix the width, it will grow/shrink as it must to accommodate its contents.